# Negative band values for LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2 after applying scale factors

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

After applying scale factors to images in the `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2` collection, as [prescribed in the EE data-set catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#description), I expected the `SR_B.` bands to have values between `0` and `1`. However, some pixels are negative. Is this to be expected?

```
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2/LC08_142040_20210507')
var scaled = applyScaleFactors(image)

Map.addLayer(scaled.select('SR_B4').lt(0), null, 'Negative red')
Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point([84.4496, 28.9224]), 13)


function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
    .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
}
```

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a22dcaa30dffb734fc57effe9d84f35) is a script with some additional layers added for debugging. Use the inspector in the EE Code Editor and inspect a white `Negative red` pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "known" issue with the current surface reflectance computation.

In this case, the negative values are in pixels already flagged as cloud-shadow.

Comment: So it's safe to `clamp(0, 1)` then, I assume?

Comment: Yes...  although you'd probably be better off discarding those pixels as part of the masking.